# Create Dictionary(of Dictionary) using Grouping in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I know I could do this with loops (as a matter of fact, I currently am, but I am trying to learn / imporve my Linq skills and i also hope it will provide a more efficent solution. So, here's my scenario:

Say I have the following 3 lists (I'm just making up a similar example, so forgive it's stupidity):

```
Dim lstTeachers as New List(of string)
Dim lstStudentsSex as New List(of string)
Dim lstStudentName as New List(of string)
```

And they are, for example, as follows:

```
lstTeachers:     lstStudentsSex:     lstStudentName:
Teacher 1        Male                Whatever Name 1
Teacher 2        Female              Whatever Name 2 
Teacher 1        Female              Whatever Name 3
Teacher 1        Female              Whatever Name 4
Teacher 2        Male                Whatever Name 5
Teacher 3        Male                Whatever Name 6
Teacher 3        Female              Whatever Name 7
Teacher 1        Male                Whatever Name 8
Teacher 1        Female              Whatever Name 9
Teacher 2        Male                Whatever Name 10
```

Where each entry in each list matches the other entries with the same index - Basically like a datatable, just stored in separate lists.

Now, suppose I want to create the following structure with the following values:

```
Dim dictTeacherSexName as New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(of String)))

Dict1_Key:        Dict1_Value / Dict2_Key:         Dict2_Value:
Teacher 1         Male                             Whatever Name 1
                                                   Whatever Name 8
                  Female                           Whatever Name 3
                                                   Whatever Name 4
                                                   Whatever Name 9
Teacher 2 ...
```

... I hope this explains what I'm looking to accomplish.

Now, again, I know this may be a stupid idea, but I'm also asking it because I want to improve my Linq skills - especially Group By and multiple Selects which still catches me, so please help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: When you say "efficient solution" with linq this tends towards "less code to write" and doesn't necesserily translate to "runs faster"

Comment: LINQ can be used to process string and dictionaries.  But to expose and practice with more features use objects (e.g. student with name and sex).   The objects will be in some sort of collection (e.g. Dictionary).  That said you have some really good answers on how to process the 3 lists of string.

Comment: Why have you tagged C# and VB.NET? You' re not helpin ' yourself if you want a Linq solution in VB and people provide it in C#.

Comment: How's this even possible in inner dictionary where more than one value corresponds to each key sex namely male and female? Your inner dictionary should look like `Of String, List<String>` aint so?

Comment: Nawfal - Sorry about that! - Good point - question updated!

Comment: Tim - Thanks, but I'm not worried about the conversion process... I'm more curious to see how to do it

Comment: @JohnBustos you should accept dtb's answer if both mine and his are ok for you, since he answered it much much earlier :)

Comment: Very fair of you nawfal - Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three lists make things a bit difficult, but not impossible. Either you first zip the lists together as suggested by @fsimonazzi, or you base your query on the list indices rather than the list entries themselves. The result could look like this:

<sub>*(C#)*</sub>

```
var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, lstTeachers.Count)
    .GroupBy(i => lstTeachers[i])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g
        .GroupBy(i => lstStudentsSex[i])
        .ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h
            .Select(i => lstStudentName[i])
            .ToList()));

// result is Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>
```

Comment: Does this work? You're grouping by single teacher names for each index, so the outer dictionary contains duplicate names.

Comment: Yes, it works. The indices are grouped by teacher names, so there are  multiple indices per distinct teacher name but there is only one group per distinct teacher name.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much dtb! I've got to test the 3 solutions to see which is most efficient, but the only reason I didn't choose this as an answer is because I can only choose 1 and this made for harder to read code

Comment: @JohnBustos indeed this answer is less readable than the other solution.

Comment: While this solution works I prefer one that relies purely on what is available on IEnumerable. As far as efficiency is concerned (measured in execution time) you cannot beat a for loop IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It's not great that you have separate lists with the discrete pieces of information instead of a single list with Student instances. If you want to use group by here you'll probably need to [zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) the collections together first into a single enumerable with triplets and start using the query operations on that enumerable.

Comment: I do agree, using 3 separated lists like that makes it impossible to do with a single linq query...well, you could use some `.ForEach(..)` things, but that's still looping.

Comment: @Nevyn Why should it be impossible to do with a single linq query? fsimonazzi already mentions `zip` in his answer.

Comment: GroupBy works on a single IEnumerable<T>, so you'd use zip to create such a single IEnumerable out of the three discrete ones as in @spender 's answer.

Comment: @Mr.Steak Mostly because I didn't know about `zip` or how it worked.  Learn new things all the time I do :-)

Answer (score 2):

This more or less Spender's solution, but this works.

In C#

```
var dict = lstTeachers.Zip(lstStudentsSex, (teacher, sex) => new { teacher, sex })
    .Zip(lstStudentName, (x, student) => new { x.teacher, x.sex, student })
    .GroupBy(x => x.teacher)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.GroupBy(x => x.sex)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Select(x => x.student)));
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and Spender! Worked perfectly... Now time to test it vs looping to see which is actually more efficient. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I only C#, not VB. Apologies in advance.</strike>

Let's start by making a single list of anonymous objects with properties `teacher`, `sex`, `name`:

```
var singleList = lstTeachers
  .Zip(lstStudentsSex, (teacher, sex) => new {teacher, sex})
  .Zip(lstStudentName, (x,name) => new {x.teacher, x.sex, name})
```

Now we can turn this into a Dictionary of Dictionaries:

```
singleList
  .GroupBy(x => x.teacher)
  .ToDictionary(
       g => g.Key, 
       g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.sex, x => x.name))
```

See @nawfal's for a corrected version of my code.

Comment: There's a little error in your code: You're missing a `GroupBy` in the value selector of the first `ToDictionary` call. Otherwise, your code will fail if there are two or more students of the same gender for a given teacher.

Comment: The VB.Net code would be exactly the same, just much, *much* more verbose.

Comment: @spender you are missing an inner group by, otherwise which it will create duplicate keys if more than one gender exists