# Create a FSharpMap (of FSharpMap) using GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking to do something very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198355/create-dictionaryof-dictionary-using-grouping-in-linq) question, however I cannot put the result into dictionaries, I need to put it into `FSharpMap`s. The data will be coming from the database and look something like this:

```
User Name   Key         Value
A           Z           1
A           Y           2
A           X           3

B           Z           1
B           Y           2
B           X           3

C           Z           1
C           Y           2
C           X           3
```

The end result should be of type `FSharpMap<string, FSharpMap<string, string>>`, where the UserName is the key to the outer `FSharpMap` and the Key is the Key to the inner `FSharpMap`. I know that the User Name category will have to be reduced using a GroupBy, but I am unsure of how to take the result of the group by and turn it into an `FSharpMap`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: FYI, you need to escape some characters in your questions: `FSharpMap<string, FSharpMap<string, string>>` is being eaten. Either wrap it in backticks or use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up implementing it. I would love suggestions for improvements

```
MyDatabaseService.AspnetDB.SynchronousReturn(
    context => new FSharpMap<string, FSharpMap<string, string>>(
        context.aspnet_UsersValues
            .GroupBy(databaseValue => databaseValue.UserName)
            .Select(group =>
                 new Tuple<string, FSharpMap<string, string>>(
                     group.Key, 
                     new FSharpMap<string, string>(
                         group.Select(keyValuePair => 
                             new Tuple<string, string>(
                                 keyValuePair.Key, 
                                 keyValuePair.Value
                             )
                         )
                    )
                )
            )
    )
)
```